# Permanently delete edits

Tags: support, edits

Is it possible to permanently delete edits for a question?

I posted an error message I am getting which unfortunately included an internal IP address. This is not crucial sensitive data, but I'd like to delete this from the Internet. (I know, I know...)

Comment: Related: [Should revisions that contain credentials be deleted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281193)

Comment: Too late.  You've been hacked.

Comment: it is an internal ip. I don't write sec policies where this ip is used.

Answer (score 17):

Moderators can redact revisions from the edit history of a post. However, this is done only in exceptional circumstances, and where multiple moderators agree that it is warranted.

See: [Who has the privilege to delete a revision?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision)

If you spot a post that leaks obviously sensitive information, or have made this mistake yourself, you can flag it for moderator attention. Explain your reasoning, and point *specifically* to the sensitive content that needs to be removed. If they agree redaction is appropriate, moderators will do so.

See: [What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or)

Comment: That seems like a lot of ball ache for a simple self-deletion of sensitive information, especially considering how easy this mistake is to make.

Comment: @ゼーロ: would you rather posts just change without any trace or checks?

Comment: If it is an early deletion, yes.

Comment: @ゼーロ what *usually* happens is that the post is edited and received answers before we come to the post. Deletion is rather drastic, and wastes answerers time.  None of this bellyache is paid by the community; a moderator can make the change, and then that redaction goes into the flag queue for another moderator to check and approve if they agree.

Comment: @Martijn Consider the case where information more sensitive than an IP address is posted. Consider that other sites reproduce SO content. Speedy removal is important, and trying to attract the attention of a volunteer moderator and convince them that it is an "exceptional circumstance" does no seem like a quick process.

Comment: @ゼーロ: the horse left the barn the moment the content was posted, **no action can be fast enough to prevent duplication**. Redaction is at best a courtesy gesture, any sensitive data posted is compromised already. For non-instant duplication, editing the post is enough as the post history is rarely copied along.

Comment: @ゼーロ: before moderators were given the ability to redact, we had to escalate to employees to do the redacting, and this involved editing the database directly. No trace was left, whatsoever. With the current ability we moderators can get to handle it much faster, and the history is properly annotated (but only moderators can see this, and moderators can't see the old revision, just that it has been redacted).

Answer (score 0):

Since you were the asker, one option would be to delete the question, which you can do if there are not yet any answers with upvotes.

This would hide the question (and edit history) from users of the site with less than 10k reputation. Obviously, that's only a partial step towards a 'fix', and Stack Overflow has little capacity to affect what has been cached offsite of course.

Comment: This is a question with a bounty, can I delete it just like that?

Comment: @Eric You can't delete a question if it has an answer with upvotes.

Comment: It also should be noted that 10k+ users can see deleted posts. Not sure if that's what you meant by "normal users"

Comment: Good points. I've updated the answer to incorporate these.