# Why can you flag your own question?

Tags: discussion

I recently noticed that I can flag my own (unedited and fairly new) question. Why is that a possibility, is this available because unwanted edits?

Comment: Look at the flag options.  They are all valid things you may want to do to your post.

Comment: That's for when you've been naughty.

Comment: Look at the first opinion. If I think that a particular question should not exist on SO, I might as well delete it.

Comment: One use-case is to flag your own post for migration. If you have asked a question that is off-topic, but is otherwise good - you can flag it for moderator attention and ask to have it migrated to a site where it is on-topic.

Comment: @the4kman: There are scenarios where you can't delete your own question. If the question _really_ has to be removed, you could flag it for moderator attention. Or maybe you'd want to be disassociated from the question, for which you'd use a mod-flag.

Comment: One more reason to add to the list "Delete sensitive info" - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284113/permanently-delete-edits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can flag your own question if you need moderator attention for whatever reason.  The whole *point* of having moderators is so that they can be there to resolve unusual or unexpected situations that regular users don't have the tools to solve.  These situations may happen on posts you've written.

Comment: Another advantage is that many of the trolls flag their own posts with entertaining content like [this one](http://dpaste.com/0TZ7GGW#wrap) (NSFW Warning), thus giving the moderators a much deserved break from their job.