# Guide on how to handle sensitive information in posts

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation, privacy, post-redaction

#### What has happened...

Two days ago, while checking the review-queue for suggested edits, I approved an edit of a question where an **API-key got revealed**. To be clear, the API-key was present in the original post and the suggested edit was there to obfuscate the key. I considered this as **sensitive information** and wanted to do something more against it. So I [searched for *«post containing sensitive information»*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=post%20containing%20sensitive%20information) and found [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86202/298845) from Jeff Atwood on top, containing the following lines:

> If you encounter a post containing sensitive information, edit it out
> (if possible) and then flag the post for moderator attention (a
> moderator will delete the post and get in touch with someone on the
> team to remove the revision before it is made visible again).

So what I did was **flagging it for moderator attention** to the best of my knowledge. Yesterday I saw that my flag got declined for the following reason:

> declined - Cat is out of the bag now.
> [Should revisions that contain credentials be deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281193/should-revisions-that-contain-credentials-be-deleted),
> not sure there's much to be gained by mod action here.

---

#### What I think about it...

I agree with most of the mentioned points in the [linked post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281193/should-revisions-that-contain-credentials-be-deleted). Still, **I am dissatisfied** for seeing the flag declined after taking action according to Jeff Atwood's given advice in the [other post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86202/298845).

I did some research and found **7 answers in 3 other questions** ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258066/how-to-handle-a-publicly-posted-api-key-or-password-or-other-sensitive-informa) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21938/questions-with-proprietary-or-confidential-information)), **all stating to flag for moderator attention**. Even the two answers in the [linked question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281193/should-revisions-that-contain-credentials-be-deleted) mention that. After reading them, my dissatisfaction grew bigger and convinced me to write this post.

*After seeing the overwhelming amount of advice to flag in such cases, I personally think the flag should have been marked as helpful. Other users may act the same way as I did after reading all the references above.*

---

#### So finally to the point...

I would like to have a **conclusive, uniform and final guide** on how to handle posts containing sensitive information. I think it would be of use to include this guide in the [*Help Center*](https://stackoverflow.com/help), so it can be easily found by everyone. In addition a link in all the above mentioned questions would be helpful as well to do the right thing without being frustrated after.

- [@Moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators): Is it possible to create such a guide and handle these cases consistently according to this new guide?
- Have I done something wrong by flagging for moderator attention?
- Do you think declining such flags is the correct response?

Comment: Hmm, that is a pretty realistic assessment.  Moderators are powerless to delete the post from all the vampire sites that scrape SO content.

Comment: I didn't decline the flag, but I agree that the "cat is out of the bag". The only sane course of action is for the user to obtain a fresh API key, and stop using the one they posted. Just removing it from the post's revision history isn't a solution; the key is *compromised* and should be treated as such.

Comment: Jeff's popularity fluctuates from time to time

Comment: @meagar: Of course, «the cat is out of the bag» and the user needs to obtain a new key. This is the only sane course of action **for the user**. Making the key invisible **as soon as possible** is much better than letting it be exposed any longer. Imagine the OP is not online right after posting and the key lives «in the first revision limbo». In my opinion SO should remove it from there **to limit the damage** and inform the user (i.e. mod-message) that the key has been compromised. This is just **what SO can do** but certainly not the solution for the whole problem.

Comment: @HansPassant: I agree, but should SO just step back and watch the key being exposed *on its own website*? I think it's better to remove it in order to limit the damage. The user has to do the rest (revoke it asap and get a new key). Another advantage of flagging is that the user could be informed «behind the scenes» i.e. with a mod-message that his key has been compromised.

Comment: SO should not be involved if a user insists on committing suicide.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Personally, I don't think that flag should have been declined. An API key is something that probably should not remain in a public post or a revision history if it could lead to a developer or their site being exploited, and I don't think this API key was just for testing.

However, I should say that not all personally identifying information is worth flagging a moderator about. We cannot burn revisions from the database ourselves, and need to bring in an SE employee to do this. Their time is even more limited than ours, so it has to be truly damaging information for us to bring them in on it.

Email addresses, passwords to throwaway sites, names of companies, or other proprietary company code generally are not things that we will call in an employee about. For those, you're safe just editing the information into an anonymous fashion and leaving it be. Also, make sure that API keys that you see aren't just test ones that are provided as examples for development.

More serious information (HIPAA violations, social security numbers, etc.) is worth letting us know about. We now have a slightly better workflow for contacting SE staff, so this is how I handle these things at present:

- See custom flag, describing the personally identifying material
- Determine if it's serious enough to require burning a revision
- If not, simply edit, mark flag as helpful, and move on
- If it does require a revision burn, edit out the problematic material and delete the offending post
- Contact an SE employee via the new menu option on user accounts, describing what revision should be burned and why
- They will undelete when this has been completed

Where to draw the line as to what's worthy of a revision burn can vary from moderator to moderator, but that's my workflow.

Comment: `proprietary company code` can be protected by copyright.  It might be better to have an SE employee remove the revision than risk a lawsuit if the code turns up on search engines.  The more the code smells of a trade secret, the more I would worry about removing it.

Comment: @EricJ.: No, SE won't want to risk the legal liability of trying to police that. Send a DMCA takedown notice.

Comment: I agree with your remarks and I conclude that flagging for moderator attention is the right thing to do. The moderator then decides about the further steps and handles the exposed content accordingly. The only thing I'd add to your steps is to inform the user if needed, perhaps with a standardized mod-message...

Comment: This answer seems to be out of date because mods now have the ability to redact things

Answer (score 18):

- Delete the post if you're able.
- Flag the post for moderator attention (Flag -> Other -> "Sensitive information such as the API key has been exposed. Please remove.")
- Once two moderators remove the sensitive information, the post will be undeleted.

Comment: I'm not able to delete it myself and therefore flagged it FMA with the following message: «Possibly the ______ in the code is real and therefore exposed to the public. I suggest to delete it in a way that it is no longer visible.»

Comment: @Matt I know. I also know it was declined and by whom.  I disagree with the declination, and unless something drastic has changed, what I wrote is how we're supposed to handle these issues.

Comment: Does the expected behavior differ if it's someone *elses* post you're flagging for deletion, rather than your own?

Comment: @TZHX Yes, that's why step one says "Delete the post *if you're able*."

Comment: @George OK -- the ability to delete the post isn't entirely based on whether it's your post or not (for example, you can't delete your own question with more than one answer), and your other two steps are worded so to target the owner of the post, rather than a random passer-by.

Comment: @TZHX Two pronoun changes have fixed that.

Comment: It might be worth noting that leaving comments such as "I think you left your real API key in your post - I've edited it out" aren't constructive. That's just a remarkably effective method of pointing out the revision history :)

Comment: @JonClements: Exactly, and that's why I think flagging is the right thing to do. Because how do I "contact" the user to tell that his key is compromised? I know a moderator can do that.

Comment: @Matt I only point it out as it happens more often than not on the posts I've attended. So if we're going to compile some kind of `faq` - it should probably be in there as while I'm sure passers-by are doing so in good faith to bring it to attention - it has the reverse effect of what they're trying to achieve :)

Comment: @JonClements I can imagine that this happens quite often... This point should definitely be contained in a *FAQ* or *Guide*.

Comment: @JonClements In my case, the nice comment that showed me the problem was directly deleted afterwards. The advantage: I still get it in the comment box, but it does not hint anyone else at the problem. In order to be clear that you have not overseen the comment, you should then send a pinged "thank you" comment to the user who hinted you at the problem, then everything is good to go.

Comment: what if uploaded an image with sensitive data in stackoverflow, it will be uploaded to imgur.com. How to remove content from there?

Answer (score 4):

**Mind that the accepted answer is outdated: moderators now have more power.** This answer shall look at the feature you can use to remove all of the previous "edits", leaving alive the most recent version of your post.

#### Redact prior revisions (so that only the last revision is kept)

See the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [Allow moderators to hide a revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274274/787861) according to the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) that is here.

1. Remove the private information using the "edit" button.
2. Flag
3. Choose:

   > in need of moderator intervention: A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!
4. Write something like:

   > I would like to redact the prior revisions because of some private information in it. Would that please be possible according to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274274/787861?

#### In addition, how should you tell someone else that there is some private information, and how should I react to this?

- In my case, the nice comment that showed me the problem was removed right after sending it. The advantage: I still get it in the comment box, but it does not hint anyone else at the problem.
- Then I should show that I have seen the comment. To be clear that I have not overseen the comment, I should then send a

  > @USER_WHO_WARNED This is very kind help, good that you have removed the comment after sending it, I will also remove mine now.

  comment (or whatever "@USER_WHO_WARNED My "thank you text" here" comment that is taken by the system, just "Thank you" will not work), pinged to the user who hinted you at the problem.
- Then I should remove the "thank you" comment as well right after sending it.
- Then I follow the four steps above.

Pinging a user is only possible if the ping auto-fills here username, that is, if she has any other posts, edits, or roles on the site. Else, you cannot reach her anyway, even if you are probably as glad as you are.

Comment: Actually thank you comments are frowned upon and the system has tools to remove them

Comment: @charlietfl right, good point. Just make clear that you have seen the remark, that is what is meant here. I will change it so that the system would accept the text.

Comment: I know that it comes from a polite, good intention - but I just don't see the reason to comment if someone already removed their comment. They did their part by letting you know - now "the ball is in your court" if to do something about it or not. The user that let you know is already out of the picture, no reason to bring them back in...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I do not think so, it is rather important for the person who is warning, as without the commenting back, she will not be sure that I have read it. Someone with many comments might perhaps oversee a comment (although that should not happen of course). Not many people will warn in such cases, and it is quite some luck for me that someone sees the problem *and* warns me. I guess that the other person will elsewise look at the thread again sometimes for curiosity or kindness. Which costs time. In real life, as it happened, I just *had to* comment back, being glad about this help.

Comment: Well, I guess it doesn't hurt. But the thing is that if they removed the comment and they don't have other comments on your post, they will not be notified anyway... (If I'm not mistaken)

Comment: @Tomerikoo You mean that if the ping does not auto-fill, I cannot ping you anyway. Good point. Just: *If* it auto-fills, you can still do it. And often, people who comment on the content will also comment in a second comment on that privacy thing.

Comment: I don't remember the exact rules, but it's not always according to the auto-fill. For example, you ***can*** ping editors or close-voters even though their names will not be auto-filled. See all the rules [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: *"it is rather important for the person who is warning"* No it is not. Why do you think thanks comments are frowned upon. They are extra noise

Comment: @charlietfl This is another thing. It is not about the content of a Q/A, there you have the votes to say "thank you". It is a quick talk using the comment system. And again, "I guess that the other person will elsewise look at the thread again sometimes for curiosity or kindness.", which costs her time and nerves (if she did this only to make sure that I have read the warning).

Comment: If someone suggests removing sensitive content I assure you they are not very likely to follow up, they already did their best to help. Some people reply to comments in near real time, some in hours and some in days even in weeks or not at all. Nobody is sitting around stressing on not getting  a reply. If they are they are simply asking for unwarnted stress

Comment: @charlietfl I would perhaps, that is enough for me to write like this. Your "nobody" is therefore wrong. And it is not about stressing, it is mere curiosity and the question whether the comment has reached the person at all, since a removed comment will only show up in the comment box on the top right, not inside the thread, obviously. I know that I would be glad about such a person helping me then, thus I do the same for others. You seldomly see such a thing, we do not talk about an everyday thing, might happen once in a year.

Comment: Just suggesting that your comment about *"time and nerves"* is not likely very valid. I do understand and admire your conscientious response thinking but SO in general does not use such principles and considers it noise. For that reason the original user alerting to the situation is most likely not thinking about it much after they leave the comment

Comment: This is a discussion thread, thus we can leave this point open to anyone else reading it. And decide on her own :). I see that both sides here have their point anyway. Good that the feature exists at all, and in addition, although it was many months ago, I am still glad about the helping comment that hinted at my private mail in a screenshot. Just therefore I take the time here as well.

Comment: Personally, I hate when people use terms like "dear" in professional circumstances; In this case, you are writing a comment to someone you know to be a moderator with limited time to devote to this message. Skip "Dear moderator"; just get to the point; why are you flagging the post? You want to tag on "Many thanks, O dearest of moderators, glory be unto ye", knock yourself out. They'll think you're nuts if they bother reading it, but that's between you and them.

Comment: Your mod flag was not specific enough. You are given 500 characters. Be specific as to what you want the moderator to do. Tell them exactly which part you want to be removed. Don't just link to the meta post. Tell them which revision you want to redact to. (Also I have edited out the unnecessary text from your mod flag. All that is just fluff and doesn't add any value to the flag)

Comment: @Yatin I see that your edits are of value (also the format changes). I just do not understand your remark "Your mod flag was not specific enough...." I do not want to be specific about the private information, even if I ask to remove it. In such a moment, I need all of the previous edits to be removed, so that only the last one stays alive. The trusted moderator can have a look at it, but even writing that there is a private mail or a company project name somewhere is already too much to write. The vague flag sentence worked for me once, it was even recommended to me by a moderator.