# Content from deleted questions still displaying in tooltip in flag summary

Tags: bug, profile-page, deleted-questions, flag-history

In one's flagged posts history, the tooltip displays content from deleted questions:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, I don't have the required 10k rep needed to view deleted posts.

I tagged this as a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) as I couldn't find any other posts about it. Is this behavior intentional?

Comment: I don't know if it's intentional, but it helps when trying to remember the contents of a deleted flagged question.

Comment: @TinyGiant Agreed - it is helpful (especially for users with less than 10k rep).

Comment: @pnuts it's helpful for me to be able to see it, but I'm not sure if it's supposed to be there or not. Is it not possible to be both? It very well may be a "feature, not a bug." Pretty much anything which accidentally slips in and presents users with *more* information can be considered helpful, but maybe it isn't supposed to be there.

Comment: @pnuts sorry, sometimes things don't translate correctly through the interwebs. Especially on this site!

Answer (score 13):

Looking at the code, given that the section of the code that populates the tooltip is in the same place as whether to apply the purplish `deleted-answer` class, I can only conclude that displaying the tooltip is intentional.

Just to be 100% sure, I've asked my team to confirm whether that's the case. I'll update this post when I get an answer.

Comment: That moment when an *answer* needs *another answer*!  :-D

Comment: ;-p If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: Any update on this yet?

Comment: @johnnyRose Nope, last week our entire development team (along with a number of other teams) were away in San Diego for the [Stack Overflow product meetup](https://twitter.com/hashtag/SOinSD).

Answer (score 3):

Given that only moderators can see other users' flag history, it follows that, if you're looking at a post in the flag history page, then either:

1. you flagged the post yourself, and therefore have already seen the content, or
2. you're a ♦ mod, and therefore can see deleted posts anyway.

Thus, I see no reason to be concerned about this "information leak", as the content of the deleted posts is only leaked to people who already saw it before the post was deleted.

As noted in the comments above, the tooltip is somewhat useful for remembering what a particular flag was about.  Thus, whether or not it's deliberate, I would consider it a useful feature (or at least a [misbug](http://catb.org/jargon/html/M/misbug.html)), and I think it should be retained.

In fact, I think it should even be extended: I just tested it, and it seems that I only see tooltips for flagged *questions*, even though they'd be even more useful for flagged and deleted *answers* (where the question title often gives little if any clue of what the "answer" was about).  I'd thus like to make a mini feature-request*: **Can we please have tooltips for flagged answers, too?**

Besides, once you reach 10k rep, you'll be able to see deleted posts in full, so it's not like their content is a particularly well-kept secret anyway.  In the rare cases where a post, whether deleted or not, contains *actually* sensitive information that really should be hidden from everyone, you should [contact SE staff](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) about it — I believe they have ways to [actually hide post content even from 10k+ users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299688/guide-on-how-to-handle-sensitive-information-in-posts), even if they're rarely used.

---

<sup>*) There's a lot of other things on the flag history page that could be improved, like the fact that comment flags aren't distinguished from post flags in any clear way.  (The canned flag reasons are different, but AFAICT, free-form comment flags look identical to free-form post flags.)  I might file a proper feature-req about that at some point, if no-one else has done it already.</sup>