# What is Stack Overflow's take on sensitive information?

Tags: discussion, support, flags

A few days back I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49421399/cropping-canvas-at-left-65-98583984375-top-389-width-207-height-361). Needless to mention it was a poorly researched one, **but** what struck me the most was that the OP has put some sensitive information about a kid, which, in my opinion, should **not** be posted at all.

I flagged the post for a moderator's attention on the very same day. But today, when I was re-visiting my *flagged-posts* section I saw that the flag was in still in a *pending* state.

- Why is the flag in still pending state?
- Isn't an incident like this one we should take more seriously? Like more seriously than some **spam flag** which gets resolved within minutes while this case (privacy of a child who is probably unaware of this) is taking days?

Comment: I would hope that such info was just invented for test purposes, and the subject does not actually exist outside of an offline test database.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: @ivarni Agree. It seems like a **school id card** to me.

Comment: I just flagged it for a moderator, hopefully others will do the same.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299688/guide-on-how-to-handle-sensitive-information-in-posts?rq=1

Comment: Additional note: once you hit 2k rep, you can unilaterally edit out the PII which helps limit visibility until the post is dealt with (you should still flag it for redaction).

Comment: @TemporalWolf Be careful if you do that though. A mod may look at an edited post and not realise there was sensitive information in a previous edit. The key is to make the custom message as detailed as possible.

Comment: @DavidG That's a very good point. I explicitly state which revision(s) likely need to be redacted and that I've edited out the information to reduce it's visibility.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You did the right thing by flagging that - it's just unfortunate we didn't see it sooner (something something... large "other" queue... it got lost... more mods coming etc...) - as soon as we saw this meta post we deleted the post and redacted the information. There's not much that can be done about any external services that keep a cache of information but I've also asked if the image itself can be removed from SO's imgur site.

Comment: Please, also update us about the cache on imgur site (once you have it).

Comment: _"large "other" queue"_ - yeah I noticed, I have pending custom flags going back till the end of January...

Comment: This sounds like we need some kind of an "high-priority custom reason", which is rate limited on the success rate.

Comment: Or, just a way for moderators to categorize the flags in the "custom reason" queue, have some highlighted when they match predefined conditions (e.g. match various regexes), and/or be sortable/visible/hidden by various criteria (regex match, user raising the flag, etc.). Based on what we know about the current queue, there are hundreds of custom flags which easily slot into categories which can be temporarily ignored in order to look at potentially high-priority new flags.

Comment: Can moderators search for keywords in flags? If so, is there a specific phrase that flaggers should use for this type of request?

Comment: @Laurel I believe many mods already do search for phrases like "plagiarism" (or at least "plagi" to catch spelling etc.) but what term would you suggest gets added to their list?

Comment: Need a "dox" or "sensitive info"  reason under whatever the high-priority flag is.

Comment: @DavidG: Just off the top of my head, "priva(te/cy)", "sensitive", "confidential", "personal", "disclos(ur)e", "reveal", "leak" and/or "redact" might be useful searches. Not being a mod, of course, I can't tell what the true/false positive rate for each of those searches would be, but they might be worth trying. Maybe also stuff like "password", "secret", etc., if those aren't already being prioritized.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yes, good potentials there. Like you say though, it's all about false positives here. Anyway, from what I hear/read, the mod tools need a major overhaul in general but there's not a lot of drive to get that done these days.

Comment: @Makyen Or just have those as separate flag types?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Another one is "PII", which is what I flagged the original post in question with.

Comment: @immibis That's a possibility, but, frankly, I trust a good set of sort criteria with the option for manual assignment, along with an "other" category  more than I trust the general population to properly pre-categorize flags, in detail. The other side of it is that what I suggested would be possible in a userscript, whereas adding a set of different flag types is likely to generally confuse people, takes SE development time, and be less flexible. Sure, it'd be nice to have a "subcategory" entry for custom mod-flags, but I'm pessimistic as to actually seeing it.